# MS Graph - Apply admin scoped permissions to normal users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using [MS Graph example](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample) to deal with groups. I have modified my code from the mentioned link. I am able to all my operations with admin account but not with normal user. I am using permission scopes as `User.Read Mail.Send Files.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All`. Once run the app with admin account and grant the permissions those permissions are not reflecting to normal user. When normal user signin it is again asking for admin consent. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: How are you requesting Admin Consent?

Comment: 1. I have created app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and I have given permissions.
2. I have added scopes in web.config file and run the application and approve permissions with administrator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issues is happening I think because of sequence. Something wrong with the permissions I had with the app, may be while approving as admin. 
So I have deleted the app from app registrations completely and created a new one. Now I have given scopes as `Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All`. 
Now before opening the app with any other user i have open below url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=a0c2773f-4701-4d9b-b197-c4ca6cb531f9&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44329/ for admin consent.

I have approved the necessary permissions and I have opened the app with normal users then it started working.

**Moral:** Sequence of accepting permissions is very important. First always approve the admin consent permissions then remaining things works well

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of "consent" in Azure AD land:

- **User Consent**: Asks a User to consent to the app doing x,y,z on their behalf.
- **Admin Consent**: Asks an Admin to consent to "Non-Admin" users executing User Consent.

In other words, "Admin Consent" is *not* the same as an Admin executing "User Consent". All that does is consent to your application operation on behalf of that Admin, it doesn't affect any other users.

What you need here is to execute an Admin Consent operation. This uses a slightly different URL then you currently use to sign in to your app. I'd suggest taking a look at these articles that cover how this works (discloser: I am the author):

- [Understanding the difference between User and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-user-vs-admin/)
- [Obtaining Administrative Consent for your application](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/)

Comment: I have used https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=75acb700-e675-4dc4-9deb-d3f68f6911b2&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost:34280/ url for admin consent where it is giving me desired result. But if I login with normal user those given permissions are not working

Comment: Are the users and the admin from the _same_ AAD tenant? Did you define your scopes in your application's registration?

Comment: All users are from same domain and same AAD tenant. What you meant by defining scope? Once I have added the app, giving the permissions to app as `Group.Read.All`, you are taking about?

Comment: The question was about where you set the `Group.Read.All` permission. If you're passing it dynamically (i.e. part of your authentication URL) rather than saving it as part of the registration, then your Admin Consent request won't work properly.

Comment: I am setting `Group.Read.All` in web.config and reading those permission scopes in C# code.

Comment: That is the problem. You need to select `Group.Read.All` in your **app registration**. Otherwise, when you go to Admin Consent, it has no idea which scopes it is consenting. See the "Scope Differences" section of http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/ for details.

Comment: Yes I did that too. Still I am having same issue. But I have deleted the app from app registrations and tried with new. It started working